# How do you use a single character PHP Wildcard to make a String Replacement?

Tags: php, string, replace, wildcard

How do you use a single character PHP Wildcard to make a String Replacement?

I need to make a string replacement in the following lines of code:

```
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image-1.jpg" alt="image 1"></a>
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image-2.jpg" alt="image 2"></a>
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image-3.jpg" alt="image 3"></a>
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image-4.jpg" alt="image 4"></a>
```

I want to replace the following string within all of the above lines:

```
 alt="image *"></a>
```

where the * wildcard represents a number, with the following greater-than sign:

```
>
```

To yeild the following results:

```
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image-1.jpg">
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image-2.jpg">
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image-3.jpg">
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image-4.jpg">
```

If possible, I would like to do this using a **single line of PHP code** thus avoiding having to use a loop statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you search the [PHP documentation](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)?

Comment: Does your input not have opening `<a>` tags? If it does, what's going to happen when you remove the closing tags?

Comment: Why these constraints about single-lines and no loops? Is your company short on new-line characters?

Comment: yes and also via Google and did not find a good answer

Comment: If possible, I would like to do this using a single line of PHP code, but it's not necessary to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular Expressions or [RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) should do the trick nicely.

```
preg_replace('( alt="image [0-9]+"></a>)', '>', $text);
```

- In RegEx the construct of character groups `[]` means that any of the characters specified in the group can be matched as a wild-card.
- Using a dash `-` within the group means that the character group spans from `a` to `z` in our case `0-9`.
- Using an asterisk `*` at the end of the character group means that the group can repeat 0 or more times allowing us to define a number composed of multiple figures.
- Using a plus sign instead of an asterisk means that the group can repeat 1 or more times (this might be better suited here since you want to match a number not an empty slot).

Comment: I've updated the code using a `+` instead of an `*` because an asterisk allows the number sequence to match 0 or more times. But we're sure we'll have a number there so we need to match 1 or more times.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "match 0 or more times" or "we need to match 1 or more times" Can you explain this? Thanks @Mihai Stancu

Comment: It means that it will match `alt="image 5"></a>` just as well as it would match `alt="image "></a>` or `alt="image 5678675775"></a>`.

Comment: Good answer, Mahai. I think it's important to explain regexes when they're given as answers. `:)`